# Lambda Calculus Beta Reduction - How do I do this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computability, computational-mathematics, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to figure out a Lambda Calculus -reduction, but I can't seem to get my head around whether I'm doing this correctly.

**Beta reduction problem**

I'm trying to beta reduce `con 1[2,3]` → `[1,2,3]`

Where  `≜ x.j.f.c.fx(jfc)`

**So far, I have:**

`con 1[2,3]`

→ `con 1(cons2(con 3 nil))`

→ `[1,2,3]`

I want to show how this beta-reduces down.

Comment: How do you encode the lists as $\lambda$-terms?